# Contrasting results between ANOVA (car) and emmeans

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, lsmeans, two-way

I conducted an experiment involving two forest plots: one that experienced a fire and another that remained unburned. Each plot was further divided into two regions: the edge and the interior. My objective was to determine the location of greater seed predation—whether it occurs more in the burned or unburned plot, and whether it is more prevalent at the forest's edge or its interior. To analyze the data, I performed a Two-Way ANOVA using the following model:

```
model<-glm(proportion.of.predated.seeds ~ treatment.plot*treatment.region)
```

I utilized the ANOVA function from the car package to assess the significance of the model, where I found significant effects for both the fire exposure and the region. Our observations indicated that seed predation was higher in the burned plot compared to the unburned plot. Additionally, we observed lower predation at the edge than in the interior, with no significant interaction between these factors. However, when I conducted a contrast comparison using emmeans, I obtained more specific insights. The results suggested an absence of the edge effect, while reinforcing the impact of fire exposure. According to the emmeans analysis, the observed lower predation at the edge can be primarily attributed to the difference between the interior regions with fire exposure and the edges without fire exposure. Emmeans results:

```
contrast                                  estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 (burned edge) - (burned interior)      -0.966 0.464 Inf  -2.081  0.1593
 (burned edge) - (unburned edge)          1.303 0.487 Inf   2.677  0.0373
 (burned edge) - (unburned interior)       0.337 0.658 Inf   0.512  0.9563
 (burned interior) - (unburned edge)       2.270 0.687 Inf   3.304  0.0053
 (burned interior) - (unburned interior)    1.303 0.487 Inf   2.677  0.0373
 (unburned edge) - (unburned interior)      -0.966 0.464 Inf  -2.081  0.1593
```

My question is whether it is correct to use emmeans to better describe the results in this case, or if only the model comparison is necessary. I understand that model comparison using ANOVA and contrast using emmeans answer different questions and have different analysis contexts, but I'm unsure how to proceed. I conducted other analyses answering different questions, such as the proportion of frugivory in the same context, which also yielded contrasting results.

I would be very grateful if someone could assist me with this philosophy.